# Diferentes métodos de criar um objeto

Tags: java, instanciar-objeto

Qual a diferença entre estes dois tipos de criação/instanciação de um objeto?

```
Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    usuario.listar();

    new Usuario().listar();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Genericamente falando é a mesma coisa.

```
Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
usuario.listar();
```

Obviamente o primeiro é armazenado em uma variável `usuario` e o objeto pode ser usado para outras coisas. A chamada do método `listar()`ocorrem em cima da referência armazenada em `usuario`.

No segundo o objeto é criado na parte do `new Usuario()`, chama o método desejado (usando como base o objeto que acabou de ser criado), e ele deixa de ser acessível no seu código logo depois, já que não haverá referências para ele.

Só lembrando que não ser acessível não significa que o objeto será destruído imediatamente, só0 quando o coletor de lixo do Java entrar em ação é que ele será destruído.

Acho que cabe lembrar que uma variável é apenas um nome que se dá para um endereço de memória. Através dela você pode se referenciar a esse endereço de memória de forma fácil e legível no código, o compilador se vira para manter uma referência correta. Sem a variável o objeto que está em um endereço de memória não é controlado pela aplicação, o compilador não armazena nada e o objeto fica "solto" e sem acesso posterior justamente porque não tem um nome para se referenciar.

Há casos que se o segundo é necessário talvez fosse o caso do método ser estático, mas não posso falar que desse caso que não é concreto.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DJG9Kk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jhgwwyeb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/CreateObject.java).

Answer (score 4):

**Criar um objeto assim:**

```
new Usuario();
```

Implica em não guardar a referência dele em uma variável. Isso pode ser feito, por exemplo, quando você precisa apenas instanciar, chamar um método, não precisando do objeto depois.

**Por outro lado, fazer assim:**

```
Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
```

Implica em guardar a referência (leia-se endereço de memória) do objeto criado na variável `usuario`.

No final, o efeito de instanciar um objeto é o mesmo nas duas situações. A única diferença, como dito, é que no primeiro caso você não tem como referenciar o objeto na linha seguinte do seu código.

Sobre chamar o método listar, creio que o código (sem variável) fica mais legível assim:

```
(new Usuario()).listar();
```

Isso mostra claramente para uma pessoa que está lendo o seu código que primeiro você está criando um objeto do tipo `Usuario` e, logo após, chamado o método `listar` desse objeto criado.

Answer (score 3):

```
Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
```

Você está criando um objeto `Usuario` e atribuindo a uma variável. Depois desta linha o objeto está acessível pela referência `usuario`.

```
new Usuario().listar();
```

Você está criando um objeto da mesma forma, e utilizando um método deste objeto, - neste caso, talvez o método poderia ser `static`, então você usaria `Usuario.listar()` - porém não está atribuindo o objeto criado a uma variável, depois desta linha o objeto está inacessível.

Que diferença faz o objeto estar acessível ou inacessível?

*Todo objeto inacessível é considerado elegível para o garbage collector.*

Answer (score 2):

Resumidamente: uma implementação guarda a referência do objeto em uma variável. Com isso, você poder usar esse objeto em outro ponto do algoritmo. Já a segunda implementação, gera apenas uma instância de usuário para executar o método listar e não guarda a referência em uma variável, impossibilitando o uso dela em outros pontos do algoritmo.